# Activity window on standard call screen - to Enable buttons

Tags: android, google-voice

I would like to add a small window (Popup) on call screen activity. 
**Google voice** and [worldcallplaceandtime](http://areacellphone.com/2010/04/android-worldcallplaceandtime-apps-know-place-and-time-of-inoutgoing-call/) are both adding the same window during a call.

The problem is that when I open a new activity on the top part of the screen, the rest of the buttons are disabled (End call, Mute etc). The only option to click the end call button is only when I close the new activity that was added.

Can anyone please tell me how can I add a small window one the screen and still be able to use the call standard buttons?

Comment: did u got any solution for this question? @shaimagz

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to add an overlay button on the call screen without disabling the buttons. 
I hope it helps..

```
    public void addInvitePopup(final String number){
    //check if pref is ok with invite in call
    if(!Preferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getInviteInCall()){return ; }
    // sets the WindowManager
    wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.x = 250;
    params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;


    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    params.setTitle("Testing");

    ly = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    ly.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Button inviteButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    inviteButton.setClickable(true);
    inviteButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invite_incall_off));
    inviteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Inviting by free SMS..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invite_incall_on));
            v.setClickable(false);
            sendMessage(v, number);

            //Track this event:
            MixPanelTracking.setPropKeyValue(getApplicationContext(), null, null, "Add friend - During Call");
        }
    });

    //closeInviteButton. ///////////////////////
    closeInviteButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    closeInviteButton.setClickable(true);
    //closeInviteButton.setGravity(Button.);
    closeInviteButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close_invitebutton_off));
    closeInviteButton.setWidth(30);
    closeInviteButton.setHeight(30);
//  closeInviteButton.setLayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
//          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    closeInviteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            removeInvitePopup();
            //Add to Preferences:
            //Preferences.getInstance(v.getContext()).setInviteInCall(false);
            //Track this event:

        }
    });
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    ly.addView(inviteButton);

    wm.addView(ly, params);
    wm.addView(closeInviteButton, params);
    Log.i("TTT", "after add view");
}
public void removeInvitePopup(){
    if(ly != null){
        wm.removeView(ly);
        wm.removeView(closeInviteButton);
        ly =  null;
        closeInviteButton = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use that i receive an exception when using `removeInvitePopup()` on IDLE state. Close invite button does not dissapear when you miss the call